# How to jump to the next line or block if an element is not found?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

my name is Hugo. I'm scrapping a website which doesn't have a button to go to the next page. Then, what I'm doing is scrapping by changing the page number at the url. So far I'm using a loop through a list of webs which are in the code and works fine. Nevertheless, in this list there are more url's than the needed because the number of items change from week to week. I'd like Chrome not to go through all the urls if the HTML element is not find.

For example, if there weren't more items at the page 20, I'd like code not to get through the 21, 22, 23, 24 and 25, just go the the Panda block at the end

So far I've tried these ones:

1. which doesn't make anything different

```
import random
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

listawebs = ['https://www.***page=1',
https://www.***page=2'
....
https://www.***page=25']

lista_todo = []


try:
  for i in listawebs:
  #list of webs
   driver.get(i) 
   sleep(random.uniform(0, 1))

   todo = driver.find_elements("xpath", './/div[@data-test="mms-search-srp-productlist-item"]')
   todo = [i.text for i in todo]
   lista_todo.extend(todo)
   print(todo)
except NoSuchElementException:
 break 
  
  

df = pd.DataFrame({"nombre":lista_todo})
now = datetime.now()
currentDateTime = now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H-%M-%S %p")
df.to_csv(f"file_name {currentDateTime}.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig')  
 

driver.quit()
```

2. SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

```
lista_todo = []


try:
   for i in listawebs:
  #list of webs
  driver.get(i) 
  sleep(random.uniform(0, 1))

   todo = driver.find_elements("xpath", './/div[@data-test="mms-search-srp-productlist-item"]')
   todo = [i.text for i in todo]
   lista_todo.extend(todo)
   print(todo)
except NoSuchElementException:
   break
```

Comment: you seem to have already exited that context by virtue of the exception. If you just want to swalllow it and do nothing at that point rather than `break` you might just `pass`.  You might want to log the fact that the exception happened as well, but that is up to you.

Comment: What site is this? I'm finding it really hard to believe that it shows page # in the query string but there's no Next, etc. button on the page. How would an actual user get to the next page?

Comment: @JonSG I tried with pass, it did the same. It continues getting to the 28, 29 and 30 page, despite the element does not appears in those pages.

Thank you very much for the comment

Comment: @JeffC I didn't post the website, I didn't know it might be relevant. You get to the next page by clicking on a next page button, but next time the items are loaded in the very page. That's why I'm getting on the sites by changing the number. Thank you very much for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `try-except` into for loop.

```py
for i in listawebs:
  try:
    ...
  except NoSuchElementException:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in your `except` block.  You have a `break` statement there.  The `break` keyword cannot be used outside of a loop.  Your loop lies within the `try` block and therefore its scope (including your ability to use `break`) stops at the end of the `try` block, or where the `except` block begins.

I would recommend two potential fixes.  First, wrap your `find_elements()` call in a `try except` block. This way you will catch the error where your element is not found.  Second, you might want to wrap your for loop in a `try except` block since you said you don't know how many webpages there are.

```
try:
  for i in listawebs:
  #list of webs
   driver.get(i) 
   sleep(random.uniform(0, 1))

   todo = "".
   try:
      todo = driver.find_elements("xpath", './/div[@data-test="mms-search-srp-productlist-item"]')
      todo = [i.text for i in todo]
      lista_todo.extend(todo)
   except:
      todo = f"Unable to find element on page {str(i)}"
   print(todo)
except: # you may want to leave this as generic, it might be an index out of range exception??
   print("Out of bounds for webpage index!")
```

Comment: I tried with your code and it continues getting to the 28, 29 and 30 page, despite the element does not appears in those pages. I'm working with this double try-except. On the other hand, could you please tell me the meaning of the "  todo = ""   " you wrote? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Right, so you have a list of URLs, if you are putting URLs in there for pages 28, 29, 30, etc., the driver is going to go into the try: block and open that URL.  Then the driver goes into the second try block and looks for the elements.  If it cannot be found there should be a print output saying so.  Or if they page is out of bounds you'll see that.  The ```todo=""``` is just initializing the todo string.  This is not necessary in python but it just looks cleaner in my opinion.  Does that help?